# Texts on the logic of chess

Tags: logic, reference-request, chessboard

I am looking for texts that discuss the logic of the game of chess. I am sure there are a few such texts out there. Such a text might formalize chess in first-order logic. I would be very grateful if someone gave me a list of texts on the logic of chess.

Comment: The "informal" rules of chess are already quite precise and logical (and have been formalized in many computer programs). I'm curious what you hope to gain from seeing them translated them into formal logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly a topic of computer science/engineering and mathematical logic has a bearing on it as far as these areas need it. However, it might be appropriate to give some pointers here for those willing to have a view from inside:

To start off, a convenient online platform is [Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/). One can then follow the reference sources listed on the website.

A classical paper by Claude E. Shannon,  known as the "father of information theory", is *Programming a Computer for Playing Chess* which can be easily found on the Web as freely available.

One can freely read online the book [How Computers Play Chess](https://archive.org/details/howcomputersplay0000levy) by David Levy and Monty Newborn. It is rather outdated, but handy and tidy. It can be supplemented by F.M.H. Reul's dissertation *[New Architectures in Computer Chess](https://pure.uvt.nl/ws/files/1098572/Proefschrift_Fritz_Reul_170609.pdf)*.

Glancing over these material, one can appraise to a fairly considerable degree the mathematical and logical content of the enterprise and decide whether to pursue it further.